# Verify Action parameters are as expecteed

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'd like to test that a method is called with the correct parameters, but I'm struggling to figure out how to validate them since the parameters are part of an action that's passed into another method.

The unit under test:

```cs
public void Foo()
{
    //other stuff
    var valueA = _someOtherService.GetA(); //10
    var valueB = _someOtherService.GetB(); //"someValue"
    var timer = _timerManager.CreateTimer("someName");
    timer.Start(() => _someService.DoStuff(valueA, valueB), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
    //other stuff
}
```

Using Moq,  I cannot figure out how to assert that `timer.Start` was called with one of it's parameters not just being `_someService.DoStuff`, but with `valueA` and `valueB` being the correct values passed to `_someService.DoStuff`.

I can assert that `timer.Start` was called with an action, but beyond that I'm struggling.

```cs
public void SomeTest()
{
    //arrange
    
    //act
    _uut.Foo();
    
    //assert
    _mocker.Verify<IActionTimer>(
        m => m.Start(It.IsAny<Action>(), It.IsAny<TimeSpan>()), Times.Once));
}
```

But just verify that any action is called doesn't feel sufficient. In other tests I can assert that `_someService.DoStuff` does what I expect and I can also assert that `timer.Start` does what I expect, but I can't figure out how to validate that `timer.Start` is called with an Action that matches my expectations.

Comment: Why do you need to test this? How can `_someService.DoStuff` be called with anything other than `valueA` and `valueB`?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay maybe this is a frame challenge then. In production `valueA` and `valueB` are set by external methods, so their value can change, but maybe I'm just thinking about this all wrong.

Comment: If `Foo` is under test, then `_someOtherService`, `_timerManager` and `_someService` are dependencies that can be mocked. They should be tested separately, and in the context of `Foo` assumed to be working correctly. The questions you should be asking are "_what should be the state before and after `Foo` is executed_" and "_does this vary depending on different implementations of the dependencies_", then write your tests to confirm these eventualities.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay is it not appropriate to test that `Foo` calls something as expected? In this case that it calls `timer.Start()` with the expected parameters (if it was anything other than an action, then I'd just verify that `timer.Start` was called as expected). It just complicated because one of the parameters of `timer.Start` happens to take it's own parameters.

Comment: @gilliduck You should not verify that you passed in the parameters that you did in fact pass in, that's an implementation detail of the method regardless.  Your test should assert that the method accomplishes whatever it's trying to accomplish.  You should verify that after the timer fires, whatever result or side effect of the handler running has in fact taken place.